# "Con yo" instead of conmigo?

Tags: gramática

I know that **conmigo** is standard grammar, as prescribed by RAE. However, on a couple of occasions I've also seen people using **con yo**. If that helps, I saw that in a Spanish language chatroom where a lot of colloquialism was being thrown around. My question is, is it just plain wrong colloquialism? Or is it possible that **con yo** is actually the preferred version in some dialect of Spanish somewhere? If so, which dialect would that be?

Comment: Can you add more context or examples in which situations you saw people using _con yo_?

Comment: In some places "yo con yo" is a slang expression for "masturbate". But it's purposedly wrong, in a funny way. I don't think "con yo" is correct in any dialect.

Comment: I've never heard that "con yo".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My vote is for "plain wrong".

I don't think is a colloquialism, nor that a Spanish dialect would admit it, much less as a *preferred* version. It is just that some people, even native speakers, make some mistakes when speaking.

My 5 year old nephew for example used to say "more good" and "more bad", and the adults would teach the proper ways ("better" and "worse"). I have heard similar things from adults, and this may not mean that the are uneducated or illiterate. Sometimes we just don't realize it when we talk, or you kind of change your mind in mid-sentence, and you end up saying one of these.

Same applied to Spaniards. I remember one of my teachers saying

> A quién no se le ha escapado alguna vez un "haiga"  <sub>(wrong conjugation of "Haber" in presente subjuntivo *"haiga"* instead of "haya")</sub>

I have heard "con yo" (when should have been *conmigo*), "andé" (when should have been *anduve*), "conducí" (when should have been *conduje*), etc. Probably I have said them too, without even realizing and without people correcting me.

So, either people in the chatroom were doing it on purpose to sound funny, or they were using poor Spanish. Honest mistake, I'm sure, but can't be considered a colloquialism and it goes too much against grammar rules to be considered the preferred or accepted form in a Spanish dialect.

Comment: "it goes too much against grammar rules to be considered the preferred or accepted form in a Spanish dialect" eh.. you'd be surprised about how easily some of those _rules_ can be bent and/or broken. I feel like that part of the answer is pretty unnecessary. Like one of the comments reflects, it's possible that _con yo_ is slang somewhere.

Comment: [Slang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slang) is by definition a lexicon of **non-standard** words and phrases in a given language. So as a subversion of the correct form it can't be considered the preferred form. I also can't picture the language authorities of anywhere saying that the preferred form involves a bad use of the language. Surely rules can be bent (poetic license), ignored or broken (bad use of the language), and sometimes the RAE would even adapt to the usage of the language and assimilate them. I just don't don't think is the case for this situation.

Comment: non-standard doesn't mean something is _wrong_. The only "authorities" in language are native speakers themselves. The RAE doesn't dictate how people speak, it just documents it.

Comment: That is what I'm saying in the last part of my comment. If suddenly everyone started to say _"abrido"_ instead of "abierto" sooner or later the RAE would assimilate it to the grammar rules. Thus said, I don't think is the case for this "con yo" situation. Take into account that "loísmo", "laísmo" and "leísmo" are not considered slang, nor a _preferred form_ anywhere. They are "improper use" in spite of being wide spread. I see no evidence that this phenomena is widespread enough to even consider it "conyoísmo". Evolution of the language and wrong usage are two different things.

Comment: But you would think that these kinds of mistakes, even if they happened in speech, wouldn't occur when typing it out on a chatroom.

Comment: @Aprendedor, I disagree on that statement. I think that plenty of people just type something quickly and press enter without rechecking. A chatroom is specially "quick". You talk to people in real time, is not like sending an email, where you are less time constrained.

Answer (score 3):

It is just a way of joking around. It is *wrong* and people knows that but you say it to your friends to sound funny or closer and make emphasis in what you want to say. You can say it in relaxed moments, or whenever you want, but if the situation gets serious you may sound out of context by saying it.

It's common to say *wrong* things in these cases.

Comment: For the record, I've **NEVER** heard "con yo", and I've been Spanish for the last 35 years, and using Internet chat rooms for the last 20-something :-)

Comment: @Jcl it really depends on what kind of chats you frequent. If they're chats filled with people who care about writing in a standard fashion, you'll miss out on a lot of slang and colloquial expressions.

Comment: @clinch in over 20 years chatting online, I've frequented all kind of internet chat rooms. I might have been just (un)lucky ;-)

Comment: @Jcl - I've heard it dozens of times watching season 1 of Dexter. Maybe us English folk just hear it differently when it's spoken by native Spanish speakers? Searching for the it's meaning brought me here :)

Comment: @ORION do you have any sample? Any specific episode I could look at the script for? I've seen Dexter season 1 in both Spanish (dubbed) and English and I don't recall them saying "con yo" at all. Maybe they say something different? (also, in the original English version of Dexter, there's a lot of "Latino Spanglish" which is way different from what you'd hear in Spain at least)

Comment: @Jcl - The episode that sticks out in my memory is Dexter S1 Ep. 5 "Love American Style". There's a scene in which a character is leading a group of smuggled Cubans into a warehouse and he keeps saying "Conyo" to them. I thought it meant something along the lines of "C'mon" because of the way he was saying it and the context in which it was being used.

Comment: @ORION I don't recall the scene, but are you sure they are not saying "coño" (which would be pronounced like "conyo")? That means "pussy", but it can be used to express other things (*ps: I tried to look for either "con yo" or "coño" in [the transcript](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=187&t=11406) of that episode but found nothing*)

Comment: @ORION "con yo" in the context of this question would literally mean: *"with I"*... same as you say *"with me"* in english (not "with I"), you don't say *"con yo"* in Spanish, you say *"conmigo"* :-)

Comment: [this](http://dexter.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Miguel_Prado) might also be relevant :-)

Comment: @Jcl - Sooo it turns out most of the time they are saying coño, not "con yo"... I figured out what that meant..

Answer (score 2):

The phrase **con yo** *AFAIK* is incorrect, there's no use really in the Spanish language. However, I heard some expressions like this example:

> - *A yo* me gustaría viajar por el mundo.

Translation:

> - I would like to travel around the world.

Here, *a yo* is an informal and regional way of referring to the first person *I / me* (I heard these kind of expressions from people from Boyacá Department).

**NOTE:** *This must be considered an optional answer without having evidence of usage or history background.*

Comment: Maybe in your region, in the rest of the world you cannot say "A yo", it'd be "A mí". That option is completely incorrect.

Comment: @serfe _...in the rest of the world you cannot say **a yo** ..._ I'm not saying that this is correct, again: **The phrase _con yo_ AFAIK is incorrect**.